# Getting Error on configuration of struts 1.x datasource

Tags: mysql, datasource

I am getting error while configuring data source for mysql. i dont know where i am wrong.

Error:

```
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Can't get definitions factory from context.
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:460)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:355)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

configuration :

```
 <set-property property="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
 <set-property property="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database"/>
 <set-property property="password" value="******"/>
 <set-property property="user" value="root"/>
 <set-property property="autoCommit" value="false"/>
 <set-property property="maxCount" value="10"/>
 <set-property property="minCount" value="5"/>
 <set-property property="maxActive" value="10" />
 <set-property property="maxWait" value="5000" />
```

Comment: maybe this will help you http://www.mail-archive.com/struts-user@jakarta.apache.org/msg13860.html

Comment: Thank Stephan for replying.. Still i am getting error when i am commenting Data-source tag in Struts config file It is working.However giving error with data source..

Comment: please post all the configuration

Comment: Unable to Post full cinfig file.

Answer (score 0):

We get this error is some property if not loaded properly. So scroll up in the console and check for the exact issue. Post the exact error to find the correct issue.